# Selenium Webdriver Firefox clicks but chrome cannot

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on element.
First, I need to hover a on menu, then I need to click on 3rd item in a list.

my code:

```
// open a list
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/span")).click();

// click on 3rd item
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[3]/a/span")).click();
```

it is strange because it works fine in firefox, but doesn't work in chrome

Comment: Doesn't work means what exactly?

Comment: menu opens, but no click, no error

Answer (score 0):

@lebs I'm having to write this as answer as I do not have enough rep points to add a comment. You need to provide some more information. What is being output in the stacktrace when running in Chrome? Have you debugged this issue in your IDE? Have you tried a Wait command before attempting to click the 3rd item?

When testing Google Web Toolkit applications, elements can get dropped in the DOM and replaced with virtually identical elements. Perhaps try declaring the element again.

```
WebElement openList = chromeDriver.fineElement(By.xpath("//li/span")).click();

new WebDriverWait(chromeDriver, 10,50).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[3]/a/span")));

WebElement thirdItem = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[3]/a/span")).click();
```

On a side note, I'd look at using css selectors if you can.